# Who is the bad guy in Aru Zombie Shoujo no Sainan?

Tags: aru-zombie-shoujo-no-sainan

Usually with anime, there are the heroes (aka protagonists), and the villains (aka antagonists).  There might be some characters that switch sides, or the sides might not be ultimate good or evil, but you can almost always draw those lines.

In Aru Zombie Shoujo no Sainan, you think the group of college kids are the protagonists, but you are quickly shown they are not.

When I heard the voices of the 2 girls, I thought "Oh, OK, they're the protagonists", since, in my experience, Japanese voice actors tend to play roles on the same side (good/evil), with similar characteristics, and those were the voices of the good guys.  Though I was also quickly shown otherwise.

At the end, I was thoroughly confused as to who was on which side, or if there were even sides at all.

Answer (score 1):

While most anime follow the good vs bad script Aru Zonbi Shōjo no Sainan is not one of them. We have two sides: the zombies, and the zombie adversaries.  Neither can be described as good as both commit immoral acts. For example, the zombies kill innocents (the caretaker in the first place), while the zombie adversaries constantly betray each other.

Nevertheless, the story of Aru Zonbi Shōjo no Sainan can be understood as a clash of values. In Euphrosyne Studions worldview, loyalty plays a major role. This is demonstrated by her punishment of Masahiro Abe and her venturous rescue attempts to save Alma.

The college kids on the other hand are betrayed by Sayaka. Who is betrayed by Takanashi. Who is betrayed by Mako. And I nearly forgot Abe tried to sell his group out too.